# Can a Circle of the Moon druid Wild Shape into a werewolf if they have encountered them?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

I just finished a campaign as a Circle of the Moon Druid involving werewolves. Being that werewolves are technically human shapeshifters, can a Druid wild shape into its wolf form?

Answer (score 29):

## No, you must choose a beast

Wildshape (PHB, 66) dictates:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before.

A Werewolf (MM, 211) states that they are a Humanoid and therefore not eligible for Wild Shape.

Answer (score 17):

No, Werewolves are considered humanoid at all times. Wild shape only lets you assume the shape of a beast (Wolf or Dire wolf is acceptable)